# Does anyone know the name of the 3.5e D&D item that allows you to store your current exp?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I have been looking for this item for a while through my books and online, and can't seem to find which supplement it's in. I know this item exists, and was wondering if anyone could remember what book or site has it listed. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site, mate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Thought Bottle**

The item you're looking for is called a Thought Bottle from Complete Arcane.

Comment: I think my google-fu needs some help.  The only reference I can find confused me on what it does.

Comment: It is... arguably, the most broken item in the game. For the price of 500 xp, you store your "current" XP in the bottle. At any time, you can reset to the bottle's XP.

Comment: by "store my current XP", does that mean that my character goes back to 1 (or 0) hp?

Comment: nope. You just put a copy of your xp into it. You retain your current level.

Comment: Is that in case you die or get level drained?

Comment: @ Simanos: That was the idea, but the fact it can be used to cheat crafting or negative level drain off all racial hit dice and replace them with class level... It's just broken all around.